# Singleton Instance 'ConversationManager' already destroyed. Returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a project of game for fun and i got a problem with a singleton who works for my dialogue system, works fine when i load the scene with the dialog sistem but if i changue scene and then back [Singleton] Instance 'ConversationManager' already destroyed. Returning null.

```
/// <summary>
/// Access singleton instance through this propriety.
/// </summary>
public static T Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (m_ShuttingDown)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("[Singleton] Instance '" + typeof(T) +
                "' already destroyed. Returning null.");
            return null;
        }

        lock (m_Lock)
        {
            if (m_Instance == null)
            {
                // Search for existing instance.
                m_Instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                // Create new instance if one doesn't already exist.
                if (m_Instance == null)
                {
                    // Need to create a new GameObject to attach the singleton to.
                    var singletonObject = new GameObject();
                    m_Instance = singletonObject.AddComponent<T>();
                    singletonObject.name = typeof(T).ToString() + " (Singleton)";

                    // Make instance persistent.
                    DontDestroyOnLoad(singletonObject);
                }
            }

            return m_Instance;
        }
    }
}


public void TriggerConversation()
{
    ConversationManager.Instance.StartConversation(conversation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure don't destroy on load is hit. Your logic here is flawed. Work backwards and see, below wont ever destroy on a scene load. If you are replacing the gameobject then ensure it has the same values.

```
 void Awake()
    {
        //Check if instance already exists
        if (instance == null)

            //if not, set instance to this
            instance = this;

        //If instance already exists and it's not this:
        else if (instance != this)

            //Then destroy this. This enforces our singleton pattern, meaning there can only ever be one instance of a GameManager.
            Destroy(gameObject);    

        //Sets this to not be destroyed when reloading scene
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little old question but recently faced the same problem with the exactly same Singleton script. I faced 2 situations that this won't work.

> You can't use the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` attribute on the
>   class that you are implementing this Singleton pattern.

So remove that attribute on your class and move your Editor logic to another non-singleton-class.

> You are Instantiating a GameObject with Singleton, and you are calling
>   that class from a non-monobehaviuor class.

That won't work, remove the Singleton calls on your non-monobehaviour class.